# Javascript Event / Sequence Question: why does this event fire?

Tags: javascript, jquery

A page in my app has some simple user preferences - for instance, "logging on/off."

The page displays checkboxes...then updates them to show the user's actual preference (checked/unchecked).

I then want to add a listener to make sure I capture any change to this preference.

In the code below (in the 'Ready' section so it runs when the page loads) I first update the HTML to display the correct on/off, THEN create a listener for the same element to capture any subsequent changes.

I'm clearly not understanding events/bubbling - when this page loads the first piece of code updates the checkbox and then the listener fires...but the listener did not exist yet because of the order of the code.

I've tried a number of things to stop the initial setup of the checkbox from firing an event - stopPropagation in the code below. Nothing works - I fire an unnecessary update to my server because of this event listener.

Help/guidance appreciated.

```
if (arrUserData.userPrefWordLog === 1){
    $('#logMode').prop('checked', true).change(function (e) {
      console.log('ON - stop prop...2');
      e.stopPropagation();
    });
  } else {
    console.log('OFF - stop prop...1');
    $('#logMode').prop('checked', false).change(function (e) {
      console.log('OFF - stop prop...2');
      e.stopPropagation();
    });
  }

  console.log('Now set listener for CHANGE to wordPrefs...');
  // $('body').on('change', '.wordPref1', function () {
  $('#logMode').change(function () {
    console.log('Fire change to logMode...');
    updatePrefs();
  });
```

Comment: I don't know the answer to your issue but why are you adding the listener in the if logic and then adding another afterward? Perhaps the chaining is an issue. If you tested whether or not the box was checked within the event handler function then you could combine your code into a single listener outside of the if logic.  Also, you could simplify your if logic to a ternary operater as `$('#logMode').prop('checked', arrUserData.userPrefWordLog === 1 ? true : false )`.  I'm not trying to tell you how to style your code but simply suggesting that it could be more consise and with one listener.

Comment: @Gary, many thanks for your suggestions/simplifications. I don’t think of the If logic as a listener...maybe this is part of my issue. I’m trying to first load their previously saved choices...then listen to see if they make a change at a later point. If I just have Change event then the settings wouldn’t be updated to the user’s personal choice in the first place. There would be no “change.”

Comment: The if logic you have, or the ternary operator statement above, without the chained `change` event will still update the checked property to the previously saved choices.  The `change` event listener is not needed there. All it is doing is writiing the message to the console. If you want to write to the console, that can be moved within the event listener you have at the bottom of your example code.   I don't use jQuery much any longer but I think you can just test on `$('#logMode').prop('checked') === 'true'` in an if block within that event listener and then log either 'ON' of 'OFF'.

Comment: As you have it now, you are adding two change event listeners to the same element and that is not necessary or 'good'.  I don't mean to complicate things for you but you could reduce this even further, for example, if you can wrap your setting checkbox elements in a single parent division element and place one listener on the parent.  Within that parent listener you can use the `matches` method to test which checkbox element was changed within the parent div, and then invoke updatePrefs() for that element. If you prefer, I can give you an example of that form of code in JavaScript.

Comment: Or, if you are gathering and saving all the settings data each time any single setting is changed, you don't need to use the `matches` method at all and can just invoke updatePrefs() when a change event is fired among any of the parent's children elements.

Comment: Many, many thanks for the help...as you could probably tell, reading between the lines, I had some stupid things going on here. The double change thing, for instance, came because I'm actually using bootstrapToggle instead of plain checkboxes (which I didn't disclose). Anyway, the element WAS being updated, AFTER the listener was created, by another section of code. Simplest answer is usually right! I marked the first answer correct because it was the truest and simplest, even though all the comments and the other answer helped me. Appreciations!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the whole code you have given is in the ready function, this shouldn't happen. The program should get executed sequentially. The code below is set up in the JSFiddle below which will show that no extra event is firing before registering an event.

```
  $('#logMode').prop('checked', true);
  $('#logMode').prop('checked', false);


  console.log('Now set listener for CHANGE to wordPrefs...');

  $('#logMode').change(function () {
    console.log('Fire change to logMode...');
  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ashhaq12345/rbnztvx0/4/

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of that to which I was referring in the comments.  It is in plain JS and I assume you can figure out how to apply in jQuery to fit your code.  There is one change event listener on the parent container.  The console will display which element was changed and whether it was checked or unchecked by displaying the boolean value.

If having a single listener on a parent container does not fit your purposes, this code should still illustrate that you don't need two change event listeners on a single element in the code that updates the last saved user preferences.

I hope this helps.

I added a second version of the example that does not require the `matches` method or searching the DOM for each individual checkbox by class or ID.  If you can structure the HTML and data object that holds the users' preferences in a similar manner, you can traverse the DOM and make use of the HTML data attribute to simplify the code further.

**First Example**

```js
"use strict";

let userPref_1 = 1, 
    userPref_2 = 0,
    userPref_3 = 1;

// Restore last selected user settings.

document.querySelector('.set_1').checked = userPref_1 === 1 ? true : false;
document.querySelector('.set_2').checked = userPref_2 === 1 ? true : false;
document.querySelector('.set_3').checked = userPref_3 === 1 ? true : false;

// Add change event listener to parent container.
document.querySelector('.parSet').addEventListener( 'change', chg_evt, false );

function chg_evt(evt)
  {
    let e = evt.target;
    if ( e.matches( '.set_1' ) )
       { console.log( 'Element set_1 changed to : ' + e.checked ); }
    else if ( e.matches( '.set_2' ) )
       { console.log( 'Element set_2 changed to : ' + e.checked ); }
    else if ( e.matches( '.set_3' ) )
       { console.log( 'Element set_3 changed to : ' + e.checked ); };

    // Invoke update user preferences function here.

  } // close chg_evt
```

```html
<div class="parSet">
<label><input class="set_1" type="checkbox" role="button" unchecked>Setting One</label>
<label><input class="set_2" type="checkbox" role="button" unchecked>Setting Two</label>
<label><input class="set_3" type="checkbox" role="button" unchecked>Setting Three</label>
</div>
```

**Second Example**

```js
let userPrefs = [ 1, 0, 1 ], 
    p = document.querySelector('.parSet'),
    C = p.children,
    c, f;

// Restore last selected user settings.
for ( c of C )
 { 
   f = c.firstElementChild;
   f.checked = userPrefs[ f.dataset.i ] === 1 ? true : false;
 };

// Add change event listener to parent container.
p.addEventListener( 'change', chg_evt, false );

function chg_evt(evt)
  {
    let e = evt.target;
    console.log( 'User preference ' + ( parseInt(e.dataset.i) + 1 ) + ' changed to : ' + e.checked );     

    // Invoke update user preferences function here updatePrefs( e.dataset.i, e.checked) if needed.

  } // close chg_evt
```

```html
<div class="parSet">
<label><input data-i="0" type="checkbox" role="button" unchecked>Setting One</label>
<label><input data-i="1" type="checkbox" role="button" unchecked>Setting Two</label>
<label><input data-i="2" type="checkbox" role="button" unchecked>Setting Three</label>
</div>
```